# Multi Join Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables which I want to join together and produce an output of missing translations.

```
-----------------------------   
 Table 1 - Languages
-----------------------------    
LanguageID    Name

-----------------------------    
    Table 2 - Phrase
-----------------------------    
 PhraseID        Text

----------------------------------------------------------    
                  Table 3 - Transaltion
----------------------------------------------------------    
TranslationID   PhraseID   LanguageID    Text
```

I have tried to create a Sql Query which returns all the languages per phrase and showing if there is a translation or not with the below code.  However its not outputting what I want, the output displays only where records existing in the translations. The below code is what I have been playing with.

```
SELECT 
      P.PhraseID
     ,L.LanguageID
     ,T.TranslationID
FROM 
    Phrase P
    LEFT JOIN Translation T ON T.PhraseID = P.PhraseID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Language] L ON T.LanguageID = L.LanguageID OR L.LanguageID IS NULL
```

Im probably missing something simple. But was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

Exepected output

```
----------------------------------------------------------
 Phrase ID  Language ID  TranslationID 
----------------------------------------------------------
    1         1            1            
    1         2           NULL           <--- Missing translation
```

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT 
  P.PhraseID, 
  L.LanguageID, 
  T.TranslationID 
FROM [Language] L
   CROSS JOIN Phrase P
   LEFT JOIN Translation T ON T.LanguageID = L.LanguageID AND T.PhraseID = P.PhraseID
WHERE P.[Text] = 'Barcode'
```

Comment: What is the problem? show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You are looking for cases where `T.PhraseID` is null and not `L.LanguageID` IS NULL, right?

Comment: Don't mix `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` - way too confusing. (Stick to `LEFT JOIN` always, as it is much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.)

Comment: @jarlh, for his need, he will have to use FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @FDavidov, that's quite possible - I haven't read the description. (Still a very bad idea to mix left and right join.)

Comment: @jarlh: (1) LEFT AND RIGHT JOIN = FULL JOIN; (2) He needs OUTER too.

Comment: @FDavidov, I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. I never said he shouldn't do a FULL OUTER JOIN - because I haven't even read the whole problem, just the code. However, I did say it's a bad idea to mix left and right joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get missing translations:

```
select p.PhraseID, l.LanguageID
from languages l cross join
     phrases p left join
     translations t
     on t.LanguageID = l.LanguageID and t.PhraseID = p.PhraseId
where t.LanguageId is null;
```

How does this work?  The `cross join` generates all combinations of languages and phrases.  The `left join` finds the ones that match existing translations.  The `where` filters the matches out.  Voila!  Everything that doesn't match.

Comment: Why `cross join ` ?   `where` + `cross join` makes it `inner` which is easier to read

Comment: @a1ex07 Not sure what you mean, because I thought the same solution, maybe you should post another answer to show us

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza :  just a personal preference - I used to avoid `CROSS JOIN` .    In this particular case I'd use `INNER JOIN languages l ON 1=1` instead of `CROSS JOIN language l`.

Comment: @a1ex07 As you said personal preference, because I dont think that would be easier to read. `CROSS JOIN` is clear on what is doing.